# Conditional Rendering in Tailwind

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tailwind-css

I am using React and Tailwind. I am trying to conditionally render `navbar` elements based on whether a user is logged in or not. The items show in the navbar but they do not change based on whether the user is logged in or not.

```
export default function Navigation() {
  const user = auth.currentUser;
  const [isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn] = useState("");

  //Trying something
  let links = [
    { name: "Signup", link: "#", show: !isLoggedIn },
    { name: "Signin", link: "#", show: !isLoggedIn },
    { name: "Logout", link: "#", show: isLoggedIn },
    { name: "Profiles", link: "#" },
    { name: "Contact", link: "#" },

useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChanged(
      auth,
      (user) => {
        console.log(user);
        if (user) {
          setIsLoggedIn(true);
        } else {
          setIsLoggedIn(false);
        }
      },
      []
    );

    return unsubscribe;
  }, []);

return (<ul>
                {links.map((link) => {
                  return (
                    <li key={link.name}>
                      <a
                        href={link.link}
                        className={`p-2 ${
                          link.show && (link.show ? "" : "hidden")
                        }`}
                        aria-current="page"
                      >
                        {link.name}
                      </a>
                    </li>
                  );
                })}
              </ul>)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have added `link.show && ...` , the second part will only be executed if `link.show` is `true`. So, the `hidden` class is never applied to the links. You can fix it by changing the following:

```
// link.show && (link.show ? "" : "hidden")
!link.show && "hidden"
// or to the following
link.show ? "" : "hidden"
```

Checkout [Short-circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation)

Answer (score 1):

2 things to keep in mind:

1. Initial state of `isLoggedIn` is `""`, It should be `true` or `false` instead

   ```
   const [isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn] = useState(false);
   ```
2. Try adding `auth` object in the dependency array of `useEffect`  hook, to listen to changes in the user's authentication status.

   ```
   useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChanged(
      auth,
      (user) => {
        console.log(user);
        if (user) {
          setIsLoggedIn(true);
        } else {
          setIsLoggedIn(false);
        }
      },
      [auth]
    );

    return unsubscribe;
   }, [auth]);
   ```

Final, updated code:

```
export default function Navigation() {
  const user = auth.currentUser;
  const [isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn] = useState(false);

  let links = [
    { name: "Signup", link: "#", show: !isLoggedIn },
    { name: "Signin", link: "#", show: !isLoggedIn },
    { name: "Logout", link: "#", show: isLoggedIn },
    { name: "Profiles", link: "#" },
    { name: "Contact", link: "#" },
  ];

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChanged(
      auth,
      (user) => {
        console.log(user);
        if (user) {
          setIsLoggedIn(true);
        } else {
          setIsLoggedIn(false);
        }
      },
      [auth]
    );

    return unsubscribe;
  }, [auth]);

  return (
    <ul>
      {links.map((link) => {
        return (
          <li key={link.name}>
            <a
              href={link.link}
              className={`p-2 ${link.show ? "" : "hidden"}`}
              aria-current="page"
            >
              {link.name}
            </a>
          </li>
        );
      })}
    </ul>
  );
}
```

Comment: The first two points, though useful, mislead the readers into thinking that the main issue is due to these. 

Also, you haven't highlighted the actual issue, which is occurring due to `link.show &&`. You have just given the final code.

Comment: Do edit the answer highlighting the main issue